# Required request parameter 'title' for method parameter type String is not present]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3, postman

I am working with Spring boot and postman. My postman request looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipB95.png)

And my controller method (java):

```js
@PostMapping(
            path = "/saveTodo",
            consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    public ResponseEntity<PloreImage> saveTodo(@RequestParam("title") String title,
                                         @RequestParam("description") String description,
                                         @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(service.saveTodo(title, description, file), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

but for some reason when I send a form-data request it is not seeing the title, when I sent the title & description as raw json though it sees them but I cannot send the image.

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @Khanna111 Do you know why that is or how I could get it to accept requestparam?

Comment: don't know. Looks good. Try recompiling code?

Comment: Is it resolved or you are still facing the issue?